# Drop Multiple Indexes If Exist In One Drop Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to write one drop statement to drop indexes, but I also want to use an IF EXISTS check.

Syntax From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx):

```
DROP INDEX [ IF EXISTS ] 
{ <drop_relational_or_xml_or_spatial_index> [ ,...n ] 
| <drop_backward_compatible_index> [ ,...n ]
}
```

I am trying to run this drop statement but the syntax near IF EXISTS is incorrect according to SQL Server.

```
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx1 on table1,
idx2 on table2,
idx3 on table2
```

I am aware that I can use multiple statements, like below, but I much prefer the single DROP statement as shown on MSDN.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'idx1')
BEGIN
    DROP INDEX idx1 ON table1
END
```

Why am I getting the syntax error when I follow the syntax shown on MSDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [argument section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx) it clearly states that

> IF EXISTS Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2016 Community Technology
>   Preview 3 (CTP 3.0) through current version). Conditionally drops the
>   index only if it already exists.

You cannot use this syntax in `Sql server 2008`. More info in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016.aspx)

Comment: I see what you mean. The page has stuff that applies to SQL Server 2008, but If Exists is not one of those. Thanks for the reply. Multiple statements it is.

Comment: exactly `drop index` concept *Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 throughcurrent version)* but not this way `DROP INDEX [ IF EXISTS ]` of dropping